# Deleting graph edges with Except

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs

Deleting vertices works with `Except` as well as with using patterns and `MemberQ`. Both methods produce same result.

Deleting edges **does not work** neither with `Except` nor with patterns and `Not[MemberQ[...]]` - instead it deletes all edges.

What is surprising deleting edges works with patterns and `MemberQ[...]`, i.e. same code just `Not` was removed.

**Am I doing something wrong? How to delete all edges except some list of edges?**

```
g=GridGraph[{5,5},VertexLabels->Automatic];
AnnotationValue[g,VertexCoordinates]=AnnotationValue[{g,#},VertexCoordinates]&/@VertexList[g];
{g}
{VertexDelete[g,Except[1|2|3|4|8|9|5]]}
{VertexDelete[g,_?(Not[MemberQ[{1,2,3,4,8,9,5},#]] &)]}

{EdgeDelete[g,Except[1\[UndirectedEdge]2|14\[UndirectedEdge]19]]}
{EdgeDelete[g,_?(Not[MemberQ[{1\[UndirectedEdge]2,14\[UndirectedEdge]19},#]] &)]}
{EdgeDelete[g,_?(MemberQ[{1\[UndirectedEdge]2,14\[UndirectedEdge]19},#] &)]}
Clear[g]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: A possible work-around is : Instead of using "patterns", just specify the "list" of edges. For example `EdgeDelete[g, 
 Complement[
  EdgeList[g], {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 14 \[UndirectedEdge] 19}]]` will give you what you want.